# Using different versions of Google Play Services libs

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play-services

I would like to include libraries of different versions in my Google Project.

For example, I'm using

```
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:6.5.87"
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:6.5.87"
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:6.5.87"
```

I would like to include

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:7.5.0'
```

as well, but I get compiler errors that `analytics` and `gcm` classes can't be found.

Is the only solution to upgrade all the libs to `7.5.0`? Is it possible to use different versions of Google Play Services libs? I would like to know what are all the different solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [list of selective APIs](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#split) includes all of the available APIs. For GCM, you'd need the `play-services-gcm` library included.

However, **all** APIs you include must be from the same version of Google Play services - all must be `7.5.0` or all `6.5.87`.